# Send Post Data by using Axios in React TS

Tags: javascript, fetch, react-tsx

Goal:
Use Axios to send a post from client to backend

Problem:
Axios code cannot send data to the backend while fetch code can make it.

The data, in relation, to axios will be id = 0 and firstname = null  at backend

It works well when I use fetch code and I can see it at backend

Main difference is the "Request Header > Accept" (take a look at the picture).

How should I enable to make it to "*/*" instead of Application/json, text/plain,  */* at  "Request Header > Accept"?

Thank you!

---

```
const params = { 
  id: 1,
  firstName: "sdf"
}

var config = {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  accept: { }
};

axios.post('http://localhost:1122/api/v1/Test/AddClient', params, config)
.then(response => {
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error.response)}
);
```

---

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("id", "1");
urlencoded.append("firstName", "sdf");

let requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: urlencoded
};

fetch("http://localhost:1122/api/v1/Test/AddClient", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest adding the `params` object to `config` as a property named `data`. And change `Content-Type` value to `application/json`

Comment: It doesn't work to use 'application/json' in this context. I haved used application/json before but not this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accept is a header to change the value of accept to "*/*"
you need to add it to the request headers
You created the config object correctly but accept should be in headers

```
var config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'accept': '*/*',
  },
};
```